# How to set multiple view resolver in spring boot Application using the Application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How to set multiple view resolver in Spring Boot MVC application using the application.properties file?

I know how to set multiple view resolver in Spring MVC application using the XML configuration. But want to know that is it possible to set it while using the Spring Boot and the configurations are stored in the application.properties file.

If not is there any other way to achieve the goal in Spring Boot MVC application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple views resolving using the application.properties file is not possible, But using the java configuration you can achieve this. I have found the ref article using you can achieve the desired goal.

The solution is pretty much lengthy and has many code snippets involving it. So I am providing the ref link to the solution:

https://o7planning.org/en/11257/using-multiple-viewresolvers-in-spring-boot